# Why does (x IS NULL != y IS NULL) require extra brackets in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a MySQL table whose fields come in groups, the rule being that only one group is in use per row, and all (and only) that group's fields are non-null.

To be explicit, let's look at some of these fields

```
x_encrypted
x_hashed
y_encrypted
y_hashed
```

I have a trigger which signals failure if you insert a bad record. One of the checks is this

```
IF (x_encrypted IS NULL != x_hashed IS NULL) ... error
```

i.e. either x is both encrypted and hashed, or it is not present.

This triggers an error in the case that both `x_encrypted IS NULL AND x_hashed IS NULL`. The fix is to rewrite it like this, with extra brackets:

```
IF ((x_encrypted IS NULL) != (x_hashed IS NULL)) ... error
```

**Why are these extra brackets needed?** I can't see how this would be syntactically ambiguous. I'm concerned that there's a gotcha lying in wait for me, I have similar NULL-related checks elsewhere that I no longer trust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/operator-precedence.html), `IS` and `!=` have same precedence. Also:

> For operators that occur at the same precedence level within an expression, evaluation proceeds left to right, with the exception that assignments evaluate right to left.

That means, that this expression:

```
x_encrypted IS NULL != x_hashed IS NULL
```

will be evaluated as:

```
((x_encrypted IS NULL) != x_hashed) IS NULL
```

So that, you have to use explicit parenthesis to override default order of evaluation.